# Normal multivariate distribution with z score zero

Tags: normal-distribution

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_m$ be mutually independent random variables.

Each $X_i$ in the sequence $X_1,X_2,..,X_n$ has the normal distribution $X_i$~$N(\mu,\sigma_1^2)$ and is idnependent random variable and we have each $Y_j$ in the sequence $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_m$ has the normal distribution $Y_J$~$N(\mu,\sigma_2^2)$ and is independent random variable for some $\mu \in$R and

$\sigma_1^2>0$ and $\sigma_2^2>0$

$\tilde{X}=n^{-1}(X_1+X_2+...+X_n)$ and we Have $\tilde{Y}=(m)^{-1}(Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_m)$

And $Z:=(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})$

Find $P(\tilde{X}<=\tilde{Y})$

So to do this you would do $P(\tilde{X}-\tilde{Y}<=0)$
And so we have
$E(X-Y)=E(X)-E(Y)=\mu-\mu=0$

and we have VAR(X+Y)=$\sigma_1^2/n+\sigma_2^2/m$

So then the zero is $\frac{0-0}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}}=0$
so then $P(Z<0)=1/2$
But I am not sure if this is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are iid $\text{normal}(\mu, \sigma_1^2)$ and $Y_1, \dots, Y_m$ are iid $\text{normal}(\mu, \sigma_2^2)$,
$$\overline{X} \sim \text{normal}\bigg(\mu, \frac{\sigma_1^2}{n}\bigg) \quad \text{and} \quad \overline{Y} \sim \text{normal}\bigg(\mu, \frac{\sigma_2^2}{m}\bigg).$$ Since the $X$'s are independent of the $Y$'s, $$\overline{X} - \overline{Y} \sim \text{normal}\bigg(0, \frac{\sigma_1^2}{n} + \frac{\sigma_2^2}{m}\bigg).$$ Hence, $$\mathbb{P}(\overline{X} - \overline{Y} \leq 0) = \frac{1}{2}.$$